# Aggregate Values for display in Charts with Sencha ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, graph, aggregate, store

i've got an question about some mechanization for data aggregation with stores.

Following scenario:
I've got a data source in json wich delivers me separate items which have categories.
I load them in a store. Now I want to display the sum of the items of each category in a pie chart.
Therefore I wanted to create a viewmodel which offers this informations and bind them to the graph. But I'm somehow stuck how to do this.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: You can `group` it in the store.

Comment: @CD.. I know that you can do summary rows in the grid; but how would you bind your chart to the grouped values only? It would be new to me that this works out of the box without manual aggregation.